# Is there a way to crowdfund patent invalidation?

Tags: troll, crowdfund

I'm looking for a way to crowdfund obviously flawed patent invalidation? Or even maybe to submit my own findings to such organisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [this](https://unpatent.co/) link which was posted by another user as a comment and an answer to [this](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/4266/18033) question at the same time you asked this question, however I have no experience with this site nor do I see any campaigns yet.